# Specification/Predicate to Search Nested Objects

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, specifications, predicate

I'm using Spring Boot with Spring JPA and Specification Executor. I have my Specification/Predicate combo successfully searching the simple attributes within my class. However, I am having difficulties searching the objects within. Do they need a separate Specification? I have a class that has 2 Many To One mapping classes within and would like to search those fields from within the same class.

Predicate Implementation

```
public Specification<User> getSpecification(SpecificationField field, Object searchCriteria){
    return new Specification<User>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

    if(searchCriteria instanceof String){
        searchCriteria.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    switch(field){
    case USER_GROUP:    
        return cb.equal(cb.lower(root.<String> get("group").get("name")), searchCriteria);
    case USER_ROLE: 
        return cb.equal(cb.lower(root.<String> get("role").get("name")), searchCriteria);
    case USER_EMAIL: 
        return cb.equal(cb.lower(root.<String> get("email")), searchCriteria);
    case USER_FIRSTNAME: 
        return cb.equal(cb.lower(root.<String> get("firstName")), searchCriteria);
    case USER_LASTNAME: 
        return cb.equal(cb.lower(root.<String> get("lastName")), searchCriteria);
    case USER_USERNAME: 
        return cb.equal(cb.lower(root.<String> get("username")), searchCriteria);
    default:
        assert true;
        return null;
    }
```

---

User Class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "USER_FIRSTNAME", nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "USER_LASTNAME", nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "USER_EMAIL", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;

@Column(name = "USER_USERNAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD", nullable = false)
private String encryptedPassword;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ROLE", nullable = false)
private Role role;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_GROUP", nullable = false)
private Group group;
```

---

Role Class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;
```

---

Group Class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "GROUP_NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@Column(name = "GROUP_TOKEN", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String token;
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------

EDIT:

Came up with this Predicate implementation for the nested objects.

```
Root<Group> group = query.from(Group.class);
Root<Role> role = query.from(Role.class);

switch(field){
case USER_GROUP:
    return cb.equal(cb.lower(group.<String> get("name")), searchCriteria);
case USER_ROLE: 
    return cb.equal(cb.lower(role.<String> get("name")), searchCriteria);
```

This is working better, but not great. I have the possible group name values of DEV, UAT, or PROD. If I give any of these I get all the Users in my Database. If I don't I don't get any Users back. How can I do a text search on the name of this nested object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found the answer myself, but wanted to share with everybody so that it may help other people with the same issue.

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> userRoot, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

    switch(field){
    case USER_GROUP:
        Join<User, Group> groupJoin = userRoot.join("group");
        return cb.equal(cb.lower(groupJoin.<String> get("name")), searchCriteria);
    case USER_ROLE: 
        Join<User, Role> roleJoin = userRoot.join("role");
        return cb.equal(cb.lower(roleJoin.<String> get("name")), searchCriteria);
```

Using the Join class from the javax.persistence library I could search the nested objects within my class with the same Specification.

Comment: Can we have a more generic way to apply it to all entities?

Comment: The JPA Specification will only allow you to join with elements with Hibernate mapping’s in your Root (as far as I know). Those are the ManyToOne ManyToMany or OneToMany annotations.

Comment: You mean to say that I will have to create this for every Entity I have, a seperate CriteriaBuilder for all the entities?

Comment: Only the entities that you need advanced searching for. JPA Dynamic queries can be used for most simple searches.

Comment: What if my inner object say Role of this question is Data(annotation) instead of Entity(annotation) then?

Comment: I think that Entity annotation is required, but could be wrong. I found this article on how to use both together. https://mdeinum.github.io/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/