# JPA Specification filtering nested object

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to fetch nested object property but getting illegalArgument exception.

```
AuditTestingPlanSpecification name = new AuditTestingPlanSpecification(new SearchCriteria("auditPlanId.auditPlanEntity", ":",dates));
        Page<AuditTestingPlanMaster> a = auditTestingPlanMasterRepository.findAll(name, ten);
```

Please find below code,

```
public class AuditTestingPlanSpecification implements Specification<AuditTestingPlanMaster> {    
private SearchCriteria criteria;

    public AuditTestingPlanSpecification(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        this.criteria = searchCriteria;
    }

    @Override   
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<AuditTestingPlanMaster> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
            return builder.like(root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue().get(0).toString() + "%");
        } else {
            return builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().get(0).toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Class SearchCriteria.java

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    public SearchCriteria(String key, String operation, List<Object> value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.value = value;
    }
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private List<Object> value;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Class AuditTestingPlanMaster.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "audit_testing_plan_master")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class AuditTestingPlanMaster implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "risk_area_id")
    private Long riskAreaId;

    @Column(name = "expected_revert_date")
    private Instant expectedRevertDate;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Instant createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;

    @JoinColumn(name = "audit_plan_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private AuditPlanMaster auditPlanId;

//getters & setters
}
```

Class AuditPlanMaster.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "audit_plan_master")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class AuditPlanMaster implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "remarks", length = 255)
    private String remarks;

    @Column(name = "audit_plan_entity", length = 50)
    private String auditPlanEntity;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Instant startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Instant endDate;

    //getters & setters

}
```

I want to fetch all the AuditTestingPlanMaster objects whose AuditPlanMaster.auditPlanEntity string is matching with provided filter value.

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specification/Predicate to Search Nested Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465419/specification-predicate-to-search-nested-objects)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, here is a snippet of how I handled it. My problem was when accessing id field from inner usuario object, in my case, id would be like your auditPlanEntity, and usuario would be like auditplanMaster:

```
public static Specification<UsuarioErrorEquipo> usuarioContains(String codigoUsuario) { 
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Path<Usuario> u = root.get("usuario");
        return builder.equal(u.get("id"), codigoUsuario);
    };
}
```

I believe, that in your case it should be something like:

```
Path<AuditPlanMaster> u = root.get("auditPlanId");
return builder.equal(u.get("auditPlanEntity"), "the value you want to compare");
```

Comment: Be careful when using this method because spring cross joins the tables