# Using Criteria API + JPA Specifications with IN Expression and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I implemented the example from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries#specifications in Kotlin. For this I extended the interface repository:

```
interface BookRepository : JpaRepository<Book, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Book>
```

and created the two methods in Kotlin in order to create Specification instances:

```
fun hasAuthor(author: String?): Specification<Book?>? {
    return Specification<Book?> { book, cq, cb -> cb.equal(book.get<Any>("author"), author) }
}

fun titleContains(title: String): Specification<Book?>? {
    return Specification<Book?> { book, cq, cb: CriteriaBuilder -> cb.like(book.get("title"), "%$title%") }
}
```

Now i can simply do this as expected when author and title is simply a string:

```
fun getFilteredBooks(parameters: BookFilterParameters): List<Books> {

    return bookRepository.findAll(where(hasAuthor(parameters.bookName)).and(hasTitle(parameters.title)))
}
```

Now consider that author is not just a String but an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "book",
    schema = "book"
)
data class Book(
    @Id
    var id: String,    

    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinColumn(name="author")
    var author: Author? = null,

    @Column
    var title: String? = null
)
...
```

In addition, I would like to compare a whole list of authors like this:

```
fun hasAuthors(authorsFirstName: List<String>): Specification<Book?>? {
    return Specification<Book?> { book, cq, cb -> cb.`in`(book.get<Any>("author.firstName")).value(authorsFirstName) }
}
```

However, this leads to the following error message:

```
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [author.firstName] on this ManagedType [de.bookstore.Book]
```

How can I define the request correctly?

Comment: Using the `Join` class from the `javax.persistence` library you could search the nested objects within your class with the same `Specification`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42465419/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```java
fun hasAuthors(authorsFirstName: List<String>): Specification<Book?>? {
    return Specification<Book?> {
        book, cq, cb -> cb.in(book
            .join<Book, Author>("book")
            .get<Any>("firstName")).value(authorsFirstName)
    }
}
```